# OpenGL version is few years older than laptop

Tags: opengl, operating-system, version, lwjgl, drivers

When I write a java program using LWJGL, and get the OpenGL version using `glGetString(GL_VERSION);`. Then it displays: **2.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.1892**

When I open my windows console (using the famous 'cmd' run), and I use systeminfo, it gives me not just any information about the installation date of windows.
I want to get the installation date of windows because then I know how old my laptop is. After searching the internet, I used `WMIC OS GET installdate` and I finally got a date: 11 November 2010.
And I assume that's true because I can remember at least the same year. And of course the device may have been some time at the factory or in the store.

When I lookup how old OpenGL 2.1.0 is, I see it's of around 2006 https://www.opengl.org/wiki/History_of_OpenGL#OpenGL_2.1_.282006.29

I'm disappointed of my OpenGL version.
I'm running 64 bit Windows 7. The device is probably at least from the end of 2010, but java displays an OpenGL version of 2006.
There are newer OpenGL versions from widely before November 2010, like version 3.0 (2008), 3.1 (2009) and 3.2 (also 2009)

Could it perhaps be that the JVM only has access to an older version of OpenGL?
Some time ago I played a CD-rom game on this laptop. I think that game would never be playable if it used OpenGL 2.1.0...
Or is this an unfair comparision?

Comment: It's not Windows who provides (modern) OpenGL but your graphics card driver. If you have a old graphics card, the vendor might not want to pay for updating the drivers for old cards.

Comment: So I actually bought a computer of 2010, with software/hardware techniques of 2006? And maybe I don't even get driver updates for my graphics card?

Comment: I don't know. There are opensource-tools to check your graphics cards OpenGL capabilities, you might want to download one of these and check if you're really on 2.1 or if it's just LWJGL.

Comment: @user2190492 on a laptop it is common to have 2 seperate GPUs, one integrated GPU for general display(windows apps, windows itself, etc.) and a discrete GPU for graphically intense applications(games, etc.). It is easily possible that LWJGL, or your Java VM is running on the integrated GPU, which doesn't support a higher OpenGL version.

Comment: If that's the case, how can I change it to run on the right GPU? But I don't think my laptop has multiple graphics cards. Windows device manager lists only one Graphics card. (Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family)

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL by itself is just a specification. The actual thing running on your computer is called an *implementation* which are usually part of the graphics driver. Also each OpenGL specification has very specific requirements on the implementation. And there are many things in OpenGL-3.x that simply are not supported even by hardware that were "modern" in 2010. For example Intel GPUs from around that time simply don't have everything that's required for OpenGL-3 support. Hence you'll get only OpenGL-2.x support for those and nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

You could look up your laptop specification and see your gfx hardware. This will tell you which version of OpenGL your hardware supports (this information will be available from the gfx chip vendor most likely).

Using an API that supports the version of GL that you hardware does is another issue and may be with the way you have initialized or used the openGL graphics lib.

I would have thought most drivers these days support older versions. They may not support the API natively, but I would have thought provide wrappers for the functionality in the driver. Certainly I can code in OpenGL 1.1 and see the results on the same machine as an OpenGL 4.5 program (On a quadro K2200M).